# Toggle Visibility under blender 2.8?

Tags: visibility

I understand blender 2.8 is still under development. But i was wondering why the toggle visibility seems to be buggy. Even tried giving keyframe to toggle visibility, doesn't seem to work.

Is this expected for this version of blender or is there any other way to make an object disappear or animate it through keyframes?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about unfinished experimental development software

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's looks like that this feature is not implemented yet. You need to know, that dependency graph completely rewritten, so many useful functions still need to be updated.